# Why TypeScript allows enumeration with same values?

Tags: typescript

For TypeScript 3.9.2, below code is invalid:

```js
const ResponseDataSpecification = {
    propertiesNames: {
        ID: {
            nameInAPI: "id"
        },
        lettering: {
            nameInAPI: "title"
        }
    }
}

// I want `nameInAPI`s be in "ResponseDataSpecification"!
type RequestVariables = {
  [ResponseDataSpecification.propertiesNames.ID.nameInAPI]?: string;
  [ResponseDataSpecification.propertiesNames.lettering.nameInAPI]?: string;
};
// A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)
```

I suppose it's intentional to preventing the same-name keys.

```js
enum RequestVariablesNames {
  ID = "id",
  lettering = "id" // Mistake simulation
}

// No errors!!!
const requestVariables: {
    [RequestVariablesNames.ID ]: string;
    [RequestVariablesNames.lettering ]: string;
} = {
    [RequestVariablesNames.ID ]: "1",
    [RequestVariablesNames.lettering ]: "test",
}

console.log(requestVariables); // { "id": "test" }
```

Result is invalid, and TypeScript has not prevented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually **not** invalid to have multiple properties with the same key. The ECMAScript spec allows that code, mandating that the latest declaration for any key wins. Hence `{id: "test"}` in your example.

**[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)**:

> **Duplicate property names**
>
> When using the same name for your properties, the second property will overwrite the first.
>
> ```
> let a = {x: 1, x: 2}
> console.log(a) // {x: 2}
> ```
>
> In ECMAScript 5 strict mode code, duplicate property names were considered a SyntaxError.  With the introduction of computed property names making duplication possible at runtime, ECMAScript 2015 has removed this restriction.

TypeScript statically models ECMAScript's semantics in very high precision and knows that the resulting type will have only a single property, requiring that all declarations of that property have the same type:

```
enum RequestVariablesNames {
  ID = "id",
  lettering = "id"
}
type RequestVariables = {
  [RequestVariablesNames.ID]: number;
  [RequestVariablesNames.lettering]: string; // Error
};
```

Furthermore, it knows that the following expression has only one property and that its type is `string`:

```
const requestVariables = {
  [RequestVariablesNames.ID]: 0,
  [RequestVariablesNames.lettering]: "test"
}
```

The reason the first example doesn't work is that the type declaration has no way of knowing what the values are and hence has no idea what the keys of the properties in the resulting type would be.

```
const ResponseDataSpecification = {
  propertiesNames: {
    ID: {
      nameInAPI: "id" // type is string
    },
    lettering: {
      nameInAPI: "title" // type is string
    }
  }
}
```

The following works because the values used to compute the keys are known at compile time

```
const ResponseDataSpecification = {
  propertiesNames: {
    ID: {
      nameInAPI: "id" as "id" // type is "id"
    },
    lettering: {
      nameInAPI: "title" as "title" // type is "title"
    }
  }
}

// I want `nameInAPI`s be in "ResponseDataSpecification"!
type RequestVariables = {
  [ResponseDataSpecification.propertiesNames.ID.nameInAPI]?: string;
  [ResponseDataSpecification.propertiesNames.lettering.nameInAPI]?: string;
};
```

The values of `enum` members are inherently known at compile time and hence the second example,

```
enum RequestVariablesNames {
  ID = "id",
  lettering = "id" // Mistake simulation
}
```

works.

Comment: Understood and solved my problem! Thank you very much for your answer!